# hook_preprocess_views_view_fields not being invoked

Tags: 7, views, theming

This is a problem that is very hard to debug, so any help on how can I bite it - will be appriciated. I have custom theme based on [tao](https://www.drupal.org/project/tao) that I named "clear" . I put it in sites/default/themes/clear . I'm using [simple_timeline](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_timeline) module. After creating "event" content type for simple_timeline, I decided to "panelize" an "event" node, so it will show the timeline on a side pane. I wanted to highlight on timeline, the currently opened event, so I decided to use [template_preprocess_views_view_fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7) to preprocess rows and add class to proper row of timeline view. To my template.php I added `function clear_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars)` but it is not being invoked. Both `clear_preprocess_views_view_field(&$vars)` and `clear_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)` works just fine, only one not being invoked and needed for me is `clear_preprocess_views_view_fields` . I'm not using any custom modules. The list of enabled modules as given by `drush pm-list --type=Module --no-core --status=enabled` is:

```
 Administration    Administration menu (admin_menu)                        7.x-3.0-rc4    
 Administration    Administration menu Toolbar style (admin_menu_toolbar)  7.x-3.0-rc4    
 Administration    Module filter (module_filter)                           7.x-2.0-alpha2 
 Chaos tool suite  Chaos tools (ctools)                                    7.x-1.4        
 Chaos tool suite  Page manager (page_manager)                             7.x-1.4        
 Chaos tool suite  Views content panes (views_content)                     7.x-1.4        
 Date/Time         Date (date)                                             7.x-2.7        
 Date/Time         Date API (date_api)                                     7.x-2.7        
 Date/Time         Date Popup (date_popup)                                 7.x-2.7        
 Date/Time         Date Views (date_views)                                 7.x-2.7        
 Development       Devel (devel)                                           7.x-1.5        
 Development       Devel generate (devel_generate)                         7.x-1.5        
 Features          Features (features)                                     7.x-2.0        
 Fields            File (Field) Paths (filefield_paths)                    7.x-1.0-beta4  
 Fields            Title (title)                                           7.x-1.0-alpha7 
 Fields            YouTube Field (youtube)                                 7.x-1.2        
 Mail              Simplenews (simplenews)                                 7.x-1.1        
 Multilingual      Localization update (l10n_update)                       7.x-1.0        
 Other             Advanced help (advanced_help)                           7.x-1.1        
 Other             Menu Block (menu_block)                                 7.x-2.4        
 Other             Pathauto (pathauto)                                     7.x-1.2        
 Other             Security Review (security_review)                       7.x-1.1        
 Other             Token (token)                                           7.x-1.5        
 Panels            Panel nodes (panels_node)                               7.x-3.4        
 Panels            Panels (panels)                                         7.x-3.4        
 Spam control      CAPTCHA (captcha)                                       7.x-1.1        
 User interface    jQuery Update (jquery_update)                           7.x-2.4        
 User interface    Wysiwyg (wysiwyg)                                       7.x-2.2        
 Views             Simple Timeline (simple_timeline)                       7.x-1.0        
 Views             Views (views)                                           7.x-3.8        
 Views             Views UI (views_ui)                                     7.x-3.8        
 Webform           Webform (webform)                                       7.x-3.20       
 Webform           Webform Clear (webform_clear)                           7.x-2.0
```

Anyone have any ideas how can I bite it?

Comment: Just to be sure but have you cleared the cache? Are you sure you are outputting fields in your view? Can you post the preprocess function?

Comment: Yes, I'm clearing the cache. The preprocess function is written just fine, no typos, I was checking it like million times. Its only content is `$stop = 0;` which I'm using for debuggers break for confirming if the function is being ivoked.

Comment: However I was also trying to print things, so its not a debuggers fault.

Comment: I know as a workaround I could put all logic into `simple-timeline-fields.tpl.php` but I would rather not to have to do this, but properly diagnose a problem.

Comment: In your Views configuration, did you set "fields" or other like "teasers" view mode?